What does it mean when you address someone as "Sunshine"?
What does it mean when someone says "sunshine" to you when they address you? For example: "You are my Sunshine."
Thanks, Theo.

Where is this?  Is it someone who knows you well?

That's not quite the same as this related question.

"You are my Sunshine" is a song title and first line. The second line adds further explanation. This is not the same as addressing somebody as "Sunshine".

@GEdgar yes. I just found this on the Internet.

@tchrist Okay I got it now. thanks.

@Peter okay then. Thanks.

Sunshine: someone or something (such as a person, condition, or influence) that radiates warmth, cheer, or happiness. (MW)

GDoS defines “sunshine”  as a general form of address: 2015 [Ire] L. McInerney Glorious Heresies 189: ‘I didn’t come up here to talk to you, sunshine’.  https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/azgluxa

@YosefBaskin - and actually: Sunshine- INFORMAL•BRITISH
used as a friendly or sometimes threatening form of address.
"hand it over, sunshine" (OD)

Note in the Green’s Dictionary of Slang that most of their examples are sarcastic and have the effect of calling someone an ass, wholly unsunshiny. However, we can use any positive in any language to mean the opposite via the magic of irony.
